# HTML Form Submits Even After Setting OnSubmit To False

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a form that I can't get to stop submitting, no matter what.  I've looked at some similar questions on SO but none have worked for me.  This seems like such a simple task.  The reason why I need it to stop submitting is because I would like to add some validation if a field is left empty.

**HTML**

```
<form class="application-form" id="application-form" name="application-form" 
autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="AppProcessRequest.cshtml">
...
...
...
<!-- Verify/Submit --> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" name="submitButton"/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function validateForm() {
    alert('False');
    return false;
};
```

**My Ideal Pseudo-Script**

```
function validateForm() {
    var emp1label = $('label[class=emp1label]')
    if(emp1label.length > 0){
        alert('Empty Field.');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
};
```

**Note:** The alert does popup when clicking submit, but the form still posts after closing the message.

Comment: There's a linebreak in your `onsubmit`, this apparently screwed with the attribute, as can be seen by the code highlighting in your question. Here's the form, original and fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/c654dhst/

Comment: Question has nothing to do with jQuery Validate plugin.  Please be more careful when tagging.  Edited.

Comment: @sjohn285 Regarding your edit: as can be observed in the live example I linked to, the code you posted doesn't replicate the error you're describing. Please add a [mcve] / edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Does that jsfiddle show that the form was posted or not?  I am getting the alert on the example you wrote up, but I also get the alert popup when running my code as well.  The issue is that I do not want the form being posted, which I'm not sure is shown in your example (unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the form was still being submitted was because of jquery-validation having it's own submit function.  This was overriding any changes that I made to try and stop the submit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use preventDefault() to prevent the default action.

```
function validateForm(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    alert('False');
    return false;
};
```

Comment: While true in general, OP is calling `validateForm` without any arguments, meaning the submit event isn't accessible inside the function. Your way only works if one assigns the handler like `element.onsubmit = validateForm;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in the new line between `return` and `validateForm()`:

```js
function validateForm() {
    alert('False');
    return false;
};
```

```html
<form class="application-form" id="application-form" name="application-form" 
autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="AppProcessRequest.cshtml">
  ...
  ...
  ...
  <!-- Verify/Submit --> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" name="submitButton"/>
</form>
```

Comment: That may have happened when pasting my code onto this site.  In my actual code, the form tag is on a single line so I don't think that could be the cause.

Comment: @sjohn285, as we only can try to find a solution based on the code you have posted here, there is little we can do about the issue in your personal environment....thanks.